# What is valid use case for `smartindent`?

Tags: indentation

I might not have discovered everything about it, but the `smartindent` option has given me much more trouble than usefulness. For example, it indents a line beginning with `for` or `if`, and won't shift a line beginning with `#`. Probably I'm wrong having this option on when editing normal text files (not programs). But I'm wondering where this option can ever be useful, given the fact that you have `cindent` for C programs and various plugins for other specific languages.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example typing the following into `vim --clean`, with each option set:

```
hello {
world
foo;
bar
}
```

`smartindent` only:

```
hello {
    world
    foo;
    bar
}
```

`cindent` only:

```
hello {
    world
        foo;
    bar
}
```

As you can see with `cindent`, vim tries to continue lines that are incomplete (i.e., without semicolon).  If your language is c-like, this behavior is smart.  On the other hand, if your language uses braces but no semicolons, this would be undesirable.

Note that `cindent` has many more options via `cinoptions` and can be configured to suit many languages.  This example demonstrates just the default behavior with no additional configuration.

Answer (score 0):

According to `:help 'smartindent'`:

> Do smart autoindenting when starting a new line.  Works for C-like
>       programs, but can also be used for other languages.  'cindent' does
>       something like this, works better in most cases, but is more strict,
>       see |C-indenting|.  When 'cindent' is on or 'indentexpr' is set,
>       setting 'si' has no effect.  'indentexpr' is a more advanced
>       alternative.

Thus, there are several options that work in the same context. I suspect that this is primarily for historical reasons. Vim tries very hard not to break backwards compatibility. Thus, if a setting is improved in a way that might break things, the Vim way is to introduce a new setting. Perhaps some users prefer the old way. Thus, judging from the documentation, it appears that `smartindent` is an earlier approach to indenting C-like code.

Finally, the documented behavior tells us that it's specifically aimed at C and similar languages. Thus, it's to be expected that it would cause problems in plain text files, Python, Javascript, etc. Better to set it in a filetype autocommand if you want it. Personally, I find that `:set autoindent` meets my needs just fine, since I never write C code.